# Trouble updating Laravel platform with LaravelShift due to dependency conflicts

Tags: php, laravel, dependencies

We're encountering some challenges while updating a Laravel platform using LaravelShift. Currently, we're in the process of transitioning from version 5.7 to 10, specifically targeting the version change from 7.29 to 8.83.

Our platform, being a bit dated, is causing several dependency issues during the "composer update" process. Specifically, we're facing problems with gurmanalexander/laravel-metrics 1.0.5 and hashids/hashids^3.0.

For gurmanalexander/laravel-metrics, we've received the following output from PowerShell:

```
- illuminate/support[v5.6.0, ..., 5.8.x-dev] require php ^7.1.3 -> your php version (8.0.2) does not satisfy that requirement.
- Root composer.json requires gurmanalexander/laravel-metrics 1.0.5 -> satisfiable by gurmanalexander/laravel-metrics[1.0.5].
- Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v8.83.1 (conflict analysis result)
- gurmanalexander/laravel-metrics 1.0.5 requires illuminate/support 5.1.*|5.2.*|5.3.*|5.4.*|5.5.*|5.* -> satisfiable by illuminate/support[v5.0.0, ..., 5.8.x-dev].
- Only one of these can be installed: illuminate/support[dev-master, v5.0.0, ..., 5.8.x-dev, v6.0.0, ..., 6.x-dev, v7.0.0, ..., 7.x-dev, v8.0.0, ..., 8.x-dev, v9.0.0-beta.1, ..., 9.x-dev, v10.0.0, ..., 10.x-dev, 11.x-dev], laravel/framework[v8.83.0, ..., 8.x-dev]. laravel/framework replaces illuminate/support and thus cannot coexist with it.
```

And for hashids/hashids^3.0:

```
- Root composer.json requires hashids/hashids ^3.0 -> satisfiable by hashids/hashids[3.0.0].
- hashids/hashids 3.0.0 requires php ^7.1.3 -> your php version (8.0.2) does not satisfy that requirement.
```

We've attempted solutions like composer update and composer update --ignore-platform-reqs, but the issue persists, we also already tried inline version alias with illuminta/support but it doesn't work

Could someone provide guidance on how to resolve these dependency conflicts? Any assistance would be greatly appreciated.

Thank you.

Comment: You want `"hashids/hashids":"^4.1.0"` version that supports version of PHP you have installed there. Second one, `gurmanalexander/laravel-metrics` package is too old that even doesn't support PHP v8 (notice that PHP bellow 8.2 is not supported by PHP team). Suggestion would be to find another package, or to fork current one and make changes yourself that would satisfy newer PHP and Laravel versions. Check that package is not being maintained for 6-7 years now.